# Display message if no row count in Group

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2012

I have report with group header. But I'm not sure how to display message

when no row count (no data under Group Header).

OR

if no row count then hide the text border around the column so we can see like a blank row.

Anyone have any way can help?

Note: It does work *without Group Header*

Comment: You must admit that there can only be a group header when there is a row for that group. Without that row, the group just doesn't exist. Therefore, the row count of a group can't be zero.

Comment: Joel, please update your question to show your report design and a sample of the data with expected results. As Wolfgang pointed out, a row group cannot exist unless there is data in it, so when you said it works without the group header you confused me. Post as much relevant info as you can.

Comment: This is query, SELECT COUNT(CustomerID), Country
FROM Customers
GROUP BY Country.  On the report we have Group name Country and under this group will show records .                                                                     If the country does not have any record then will display message "NO DATA" for example.

Comment: how to insert image so you can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a separate table for Countries? I don't see how you could have Japan from your query without a count for it.

I think it would be better to get all of your countries and them JOIN your results to it so the query always has data for all countries.

```
SELECT 'Germany' AS Country
INTO #Countries 
UNION
SELECT 'Italy' AS Country
UNION
SELECT 'Japan' AS Country

SELECT 1 CustomerID, 'Germany' Country
INTO #Customers 
UNION
SELECT 2 CustomerID, 'Germany' Country
UNION
SELECT 3 CustomerID, 'Italy' Country
UNION
SELECT 4 CustomerID, 'Italy' Country
UNION
SELECT 5 CustomerID, 'Italy' Country
UNION
SELECT 6 CustomerID, 'Italy' Country



SELECT COUNT(CustomerID) COUNTRY_COUNT, C1.Country 
FROM #Countries AS C1
LEFT JOIN #Customers C2 ON C2.Country = C1.Country
GROUP BY C1.Country
```

This will give a count of **0** for Japan.

Comment: Forget the count , the table customer simple with custonerid, lname and country. Query select from * customer. Focus on SSRS report and see the lay out above. You can create on your own and test out. Thank you.

Comment: @joel - I don't see how your table can be showing JAPAN if JAPAN isn't in your Customer table. But since your table has a blank row under JAPAN, you could try `=IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!CustomerID.value), "No Data", Fields!CustomerID.value)` .

Comment: You can made it up any data in the table and test .

Comment: @joel - Sorry, I made the #Customer table but wasn't able to get Japan out of it so that's why I went with the country table. I must be missing/misunderstanding something :(

Answer (score 0):

[image]

this is sample of my SSRS report by group COUNTRY

Answer (score 0):

[image]

group with record under country group

Answer (score 0):

[image]

if no record under country group then need display message 'No Data'